# Youtube embed doesnt work with % parameter

Tags: html, css, youtube, embed

Alright so I'm having trouble getting the embed youtube-clip to be % width/height. Trying to make a website that looks the same no matter what resolution you have.

How do I make them use the % instead of px?

```
<table id="tableframsida" align="center" border="0" height="80%">  
    <tr>
        <td height="100%">
            <h2>HeatoN explains how to think when you're creating tactics</h2>
        </td>
        <td height="100%">
            <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/UTdFMBReXBw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</table>
```

Comment: Using tables for layout is a bad practice: they are meant to be used to display data.

Comment: I'm very bad at html so I don't know how to do it otherwise. Tips?

Comment: @SebastianInsomniiaJönsson it's hard to tell without seeing your HTML, but there's the `display:table` CSS property that acts like a table, but isn't non-semantic.

Comment: You want your caption and your iframe side by side? Plus, you forgot to close both last `td` and `tr`. @JanDvorak His HTML is on his question

Comment: @Bigood Yes, thats exactly what i want. Right now i found out i can position them all with margin-top and margin-left but it gets kind of messy

Comment: It's not really clear what layout you want here. What are those percentages in relation to? How big do you want the video to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With so few informations about the layout you'd want, I propose you this HTML / CSS you can adjust to fit your requirement.

- I removed the `width=100%` and `height=100%` of the iframe, which are the default values for iframes
- I changed the table display for a classic wrapping div + elements and a `display:inline-block`.

### HTML

```
<div class="videoWrapper">
    <h2>HeatoN explains how to think when you're creating tactics</h2>
    <iframe  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/UTdFMBReXBw" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.videoWrapper{
    height:600px;
}

.videoWrapper h2, .videoWrapper iframe{
    display:inline-block;
}
.videoWrapper h2{
    word-wrap:;
    width:25%;
}
.videoWrapper iframe{
    width:70%;
}
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gFpWt/)